# angularjs - How to lazy load templates from templateCache in directive

Tags: templates, angularjs, lazy-loading, directive

I am trying to display the details of items in a list. This should be done by lazy loading the template (DOM for the details), because the template is very large and i've got many items in the list so a ng-show with ng-include is not working, since it is compiled into the DOM and makes the performance very bad.

After experimenting I figured out a solution, only working with a inline template. I am using a click handler to render the HTML with the detail-view directive to the DOM.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    {{item.name}} <button show-on-click item="item">Show Details</button>  

    <div class="detailView"></div>

    <div ng-include="'include.html'"></div>
</div>

<!-- detailView Template -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="detailView.html">
    <p>With external template: <span>{{details.description}}</span></p>
</script>
```

**Show On Click Directive**

```
myApp.directive("showOnClick", ['$compile', '$parse', function($compile, $parse) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      item: "=item"
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        // Bind the click handler
        element.bind('click', function() {
            // Parse the item
            var item = $parse(attrs.item)(scope);

            // Find the element to include the details
            var next = $(element).next('div.detailView');

            // Include and Compile new html with directiv
            next.replaceWith($compile('<detail-view details="item"></detail-view>')(scope));

        });
     }
   };
}]);
```

**Detail View Directive:**

```
myApp.directive("detailView", ['$parse', '$templateCache', '$http', function($parse, $templateCache, $http) {    
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'detailView.html', // this is not working
    // template: "<div>With template in directive: <span>{{details.description}}</span></div>", // uncomment this line to make it work
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var item = $parse(attrs.details)(scope);
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.details = item.details;
        });
    }        
  };
}]);
```

Here is the full example on
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YBqJ0gVMK9zD9X47GeN7?p=preview)

Is there a way to improve my solution, or what am I missing to load the external template?
Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also look at `ng-if` directive in Angular version 1.1.5 . [ng-if](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angIf) would only render the html if condition is true. So this becomes

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    {{item.name}} <button ng-if="showDetails" item="item" ng-click='showDetails=true'>Show Details</button>  

    <div class="detailView"></div>

    <div ng-include="'include.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By just using **ng-include**:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-init="detailsViewTemplateSource='';">
    {{item.name}} 
    <button ng-click="detailsViewTemplateSource = 'detailView.html'">
        Show Details
    </button>       
    <div ng-include="detailsViewTemplateSource"></div>
</div>

<!-- detailView Template -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="detailView.html">
    <p>With external template: <span>{{details.description}}</span></p>
</script>
```